# Add styles to dynamically added elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, addition, dynamic

heres the demo

http://lufi.realservers.info/demos/add_forms_dynamically/

when i add another element (input boxes) i cannot remove the italicized-grayed labels inside
unlike the first input boxes. Also, they only disappear if I click the first set of input boxes.

are there any other ways to add styles to dynamically added elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to apply it to dynamically added element.

Comment: thanks actually saw this lol .maybe next time i should search here more .than ask a question thanks :)

Comment: Here is the link for more details http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/06/jquery-live-function-exampledemo.html. I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

As well as using live for your events (which will apply to things not yet in the dom but will add events when they get added) you might also want to change your function that remove the text from the input because at the moment it will just remove all, which is probably not what you are wanting.

Instead of:

```
$('.inbox').css('color','black');
$('.inbox').css('font-style','normal');
$('.inbox').val('');
```

Try

```
$(this).css({'color': 'black', 'font-style': 'normal'}).val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also go for `jQuery.delegate()`