# Adding style to dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/k7mmybje/). Why am I not able to add margin to dynamically generated divs?

```
jQuery(function () {
    var rnd1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 450);
    var rnd2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 450);
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box"></div>');
        //        $('.box').css({"left": rnd1,"top": rnd2});
    }
    $(".box").each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "left": rnd1,
            "top": rnd2
        });
    });
```

As you can see I tried both:

```
$('.box').css({"left": rnd1,"top": rnd2});
```

inside the loop and using `.each()` as:

```
 $(".box").each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "left": rnd1,
            "top": rnd2
        });
    });
```

out of the loop but apparently they are not doing the job!

Comment: Why don't you define `.someClass` with the required CSS attributed and `.toggleClass("someClass")` within your `.each()` loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add styles to dynamically added elements with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505218/add-styles-to-dynamically-added-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: Another duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717257/jquery-css-for-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @royhowie - A question with the answer "you can use `live`..." isn't really a duplicate, it's just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not adding margin, you're setting the `top` and `left` position, and that only works if the element doesn't have a static position

```
$(this).css({"left": rnd1,"top": rnd2, position: 'relative'});
```

or you could actually add margin instead

```
$(this).css({"margin-left": rnd1, "margin-top": rnd2});
```

As a sidenote, you can add the styles when you're creating the elements, the second loop is uneccessary

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    $('.wrapper').append(
        $('<div />', {
            'class' : 'box',
            css : {
                marginLeft : rnd1,
                marginTop  : rnd2
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank adeneo but this is causing some issues as well. can you please take a look at here :http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/k7mmybje/1/

Comment: It works exactly as intended, but probably not as you're expecting. What did you expect would happen ?

Comment: Well I just want the boxe be separated randomly inside the wrapper class. thats why i tried to use left and right

Comment: Then you'd have to get the random values inside the loop, right now you have ***one*** random number, and you're using it for ***all*** the boxes.

Comment: As margin always keep the same size for them besides it doesn't look it is iterating the margins!

Comment: well this one looks better but how can I stop occuering the boxes out of wrapper!

Comment: That's a completely different question, and would require some sort of containment, checking that the boxes doesn't appear outside the wrapper etc. Something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k7mmybje/3/**